# Click link in CasperJS with extra spacing in the label

Tags: javascript, click, casperjs

I'm attempting to click the download 'button' in the following image:
 [image]

As you can see in the inspector, there is extra spacing in the label, so simply doing:

```
this.clickLabel("Download", "a");
```

doesn't work.

I've tried cutting and pasting the text from the html, but the nature of the return character producing a parsing error.

Any ideas?

Update:
@Artom B.'s duplicate link does have a potential solution to the problem, but the question being asked by the user is not the same and difficult to find otherwise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I click a link using CasperJS without knowing the css selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803443/how-can-i-click-a-link-using-casperjs-without-knowing-the-css-selector)

Comment: Not exactly the same, but the `^=` might be the key to the solution. I'll try that and report back.

Comment: No, more the second half of the answer.

Comment: Cutting and pasting the text from the inspector doesn't work. How is that different than what I said doesn't work? Is it the "contains" that's suppose to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Artjom B. I came to use:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.click(x("//a[contains(text(), 'Download')]"));
```

Essentially, the problem of having trailing characters after "Download" is overcome by searching for any link that contains "Download". When utilizing this, be weary that it will cause problems if another link also contains "Download" in the page.

Note: This is similar to the duplicate link Artjom commented on the question, but I think the problem is unique and the title is better related to that problem.

Comment: You have a bunch of comments around a small code dump. You should describe why this solves the problem.